# GMSAutocompleteViewController remove the "cancel" button

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swiftui

I am trying to delete the default "cancel" button in the GMSAutocompleteViewController of google maps API for ios. How do I do this? is this possible?

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: you can manually creat search bar and then hide button check out this https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete and for hide button you can do like searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You can disable cancel button from UISearchBar Delegate method.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
}
```

if you are using CustomSearchBar

CustomSearchBar.swift

```
import UIKit

class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GMSAutocompleteViewController don't have any reference of "SearchBar" object to change or hide "cancel" button. You can check inside the GMSAutocompleteViewController there is no IBOutlet for "SearchBar".

You can hide the cancel button only by creating the custom view controller with your own SearchBar.

Comment: Definitely a possibility, was looking not doing it from scratch, but it is the option that works best and is more stable.